# Undefined function when testing public functions called in the constructor of an abstract class using mockery

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I have an abstract class which makes calls to public functions in its constructor. To test these calls are executed correctly, I have to mock the abstract class. Whenever I do this, I cannot make public function calls in the constructor. I get the the following error: `BadMethodCallException: Method ::setData() does not exist on this mock object`. The following code probably explains my issue better.

```
<?php

namespace Example\Tests;

use Mockery as m;
use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase;

abstract class Foo
{

    private $data;

    public function __construct(array $defaults)
    {
        foreach ($defaults as $key => $value) {
            $this->setData($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    public function setData($key, $value)
    {
        return $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }
}


class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testDefaultsAreAssignedToData()
    {
        $expected = ['foo' => 'bar'];

        $foo = m::mock('\Example\Tests\Foo', [$expected]);

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $foo->getData());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you are using mocks as a replacement for external dependencies for your class under test. In this case you just want to test the real behaviour of the class, and you are not dealing with any dependencies for the class `Foo`. In this case there is really no need to mock, I would just define a concrete instance of the abstract class for testing purposes. 
That said, you can refactor to something like this.

```
class ConcreteFoo extends Foo
{
}

class ExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testDefaultsAreAssignedToData()
    {
        $expected = ['foo' => 'bar'];

        $foo = new ConcreteFoo($expected);

        $this->assertEquals($expected, $foo->getData());
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I might end up going with that, I was hoping there would be something in Mockery to do this though.

Comment: This doesn't test the constructor in isolation. It tests the getData method in addition, which isn't called in the constructor. The trick is to test whether setData is called (with the expected array) without using getData.